# prototype issue in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, prototype

I have the following piece of code:

```
function University(name) {
    this.name = name
}
University.prototype = {
    sayName: function() {
        console.log(this.name)
    },
    toString: function() {
        console.log("WUSTL")
    }
};
var univ = new University("Washington University");
console.log(univ instanceof University);
console.log(univ.constructor == University); // false
console.log(univ.constructor == Object);     // true
```

can anybody help to explain why the constructor of the instance of 'University' got changed to Object instead of University?

Comment: You need to reset the prototype whenever you overwrite the it: `University.prototype.constructor = University;`. An useful [link](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/06/07/understanding-javascript-prototypes/) about Prototypes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you overwrote the original prototype which knew the identity of the constructor.